# why function connect no answer? "Cannot set property 'collection' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Everything worked until I put the db.collection function inside "com". Now he returns the error "Cannot set property 'collection' of undefined". Why is this effect?

```
"use strict";
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var mongoUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
var database = 'ks';

function DB(command, collection, args, call) {
    this.collection = collection
    MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err, dbo) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        var db = dbo.db(database);
        if (err) throw err;

        var com = {
            find: db.collection(this.collection).find(args).toArray((err, data) => {
                if(err) throw err;
                call(data);
            })
        }

        dbo.close();

        return com['find'];
    })
}
// console.log(find('characters',{name: "Dawid"}))
DB('characters',{name: "Dawid"}, (call) => {
    console.log(call)
})
```

Comment: Look at the stack trace to see which line it's happening on. It has nothing to do with `db.collection`.

Comment: What is `this.collection = collection` supposed to do?

Comment: without this.collection = collection i had error "collection must by a string"

Comment: That does not answer my question.

Comment: pass parameter ... I thought db.collection just can't see this parameter and that's why there is an error.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried to bind your this to a variable and passing it like that?

`var that = this;`

`... db.collection(that.collection)...`

It might (very likely is) be that the `this` is lost when you package it into a JS Object. With the `var that = this`, you bind the current context's `this` to a variable and pass the correct reference to `db.collection.`

Of course there might be a better way to capture the `this`, but that's another answer to another question.

Just the first thing that popped into my mind while looking at your code, seems that kind of issue.